# p5js use loop function in main scope

Tags: javascript, p5.js

So I have this very basic example in p5js:

```
var e = 1;

function setup() {
    window.canvas = createCanvas(200, 200);
}

function draw() {
    fill(255, 255, 0);
    ellipse(50 + e, 50, 30);
    e++;

    noLoop();
}
```

if we'll ignore the `noLoop()` for a second, this code just duplicate a circle and make it forward to the right.

Now, I'm trying to control the amount of frames that being played by adding that:

```
function makeOneMove() {
    loop();
}
```

so whenever I'll call `makeOneMove()` for example just as is in my script, I expect from it to play one frame.

But, sadly I receive that error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: loop is not defined

So my question is, how can I use that `loop()` or `noLoop()` functions that only work in p5's functions like setup or draw.

Comment: when are you calling `makeOneMove()`? When the user does a particular action such as click?

Comment: @NickParsons no, calling it in the main scope, just as a global call.

Comment: so you expect the circle to have moved 1 pixel over after calling `makeOneMove()` ?

Comment: @NickParsons Exactly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this frame by frame you need to ensure that `loop()` is used within your `setup()` method like so:

```js
var e = 1;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(200, 200);
  makeOneMove(); // call makeOneMove in `setup`
}

function makeOneMove() {
  loop();
}

function draw() {
  background(255); // used to remove the "trail" of circles (remove if trail is wanted)
  fill(255, 255, 0);
  ellipse(50 + e, 50, 30);
  e++;
  noLoop();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Instead of controlling when `draw()` is called, you can instead control the value of `e` outside of `draw()` and inside of `makeOneMove()`. This way, as `draw()` is being repeatedly called over and over again, it will take the new value of `e` and draw the circle at that new offset position. For demonstration purposes, I have added a `mouseClicked()` method which will call `makeOneMove()` whenever you click:

```js
var e = 1;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(200, 200);
}

function makeOneMove() {
  e++;
}

function draw() {
  background(255); // used to remove the "trail" of circles (remove if trail is wanted)
  fill(255, 255, 0);
  ellipse(50 + e, 50, 30);
}

function mouseClicked() {
  makeOneMove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

For multiple circles/objects, it depends on how you are representing your data/objects. The best way for something like this is to use objects (for instance by creating a `Class`), and change the offset (ie: the `e` value) for each object:

```js
class Circle {
  constructor(x, y, r, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
    this.color = color;
    this.offset = 1; // (circles own `e` value)
  }
}

var objects;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(200, 200);
  objects = [ // store all your onscreen objects in an array
    new Circle(50, 50, 30, color(255, 255, 0)), // original object you had
    new Circle(50, 100, 50, color(0, 255, 0))
  ]; 
}

function makeOneMove(objectIndex) {
  objects[objectIndex].offset++;
}

function draw() {
  background(255); // used to remove the "trail" of circles (remove if trail is wanted)
  for(const circle of objects) {// loop through all objects in your `objects` array
    // Draw the given object/circle
    fill(circle.color);
    ellipse(circle.x + circle.offset, circle.y, circle.r);
  }
}

function mouseClicked() {
  makeOneMove(0); // make object 0 in array move (for demo)
}

function keyPressed() {
  makeOneMove(1); // make object 1 in array move (for demo)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's great idea to be honest, but I simplified my example, in my real project there are a lot of objects that are moving, and it's pretty hard to use this tactic on several objects in the same time,

Is there another way of controlling the amount of frames that are being played?

Comment: @Dorki Hi, I've added a frame by frame example. You need to ensure you call `makeOneMove()` inside of the setup method. I've also added an alternative using objects in an array (which might give you more control if you have multiple objects)

Comment: a note that this method uses busy waiting, but if there is no other option I might using it.